# How to check column whether it is null-able or not from two different table and then do the process?

Tags: python, pandas, function

```
df1: 
   name     job       id_number  Salary
0  krul                125796    45000
1  arnold   lawyer     789632    25000
2  daisy    engg       256498    
3  alex                456985    65884
4  mandy    arch       456258    36958
5  krul     painter    
6  perry               789632 
7  timu     lawyer     
8  timy     lawyer     789632    69822
9  daisy    engg       
10 daisy    engg       256498    54869


df2:
ColumnName  allow_null
  name       True
  job        True
  id_number  False
  Salary     True
```

I want to check the sum of missing value in each column in df1 and replace with mean or mode of that column.

If that column is non null-able (allow_null == False )  as mentioned in the df2 then raise error else replace it with mean or mode as per column datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TrueLst=df2[df2["allow_null"]==True].index.tolist()
for i in TrueLst:
    if i in df1.columns.tolist():
        if df["job"].dtype==np.int64
            df1["job"]=df1["job"].np.where(df1["job"].isnull(),df["col1"].mean(),null)
        elif df["col1"].dtype==object
            df1["job"]=df1["job"].np.where(df1["job"].isnull(),df["col1"].mode()[0],null)
        else:
            pass
```

Bit more detail would help but some thing like above would do the job.
No need to handle the columns where False. Just check if there is any NaN 's in that column